Determinant of $3\times3$ block matrix
My intuition tells me that this determinant should be relatively simple to compute, yet after a while trying, I am running out of ideas. So any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
We aim to find the determinant of the following matrix:
\begin{equation}
M = \begin{bmatrix}
 A & C & B
\\
0 & D & 0
\\
B & E & A
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
Where the matrices $A$ and $B$ are invertible of size $N$. The matrix $D$ is also invertible and has size $L$. The matrices $C$ and $E$ are not square.


First observe that
$$
\det M=\det \begin{bmatrix}
 A & 0 & B
\\
0 & D & 0
\\
B & 0 & A
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which follows from adding linear combinations of the lines of $D$ to those of $C$ and $E$ (the determinant does not change with these operations). Moreover,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 A & B & 0
\\
B & A & 0
\\
0 & 0 & D
\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
 A & 0 & B
\\
0 & D & 0
\\
B & 0 & A
\end{bmatrix}P,
$$
where
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}
 {\rm Id} & 0 & 0
\\
0 & 0 & {\rm Id}
\\
0 & {\rm Id} & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In fact $P^{-1}=P$ and $\det P=-1$. Therefore,
$$
\det M=\det\begin{bmatrix}
 A & B & 0
\\
B & A & 0
\\
0 & 0 & D
\end{bmatrix}=\det\begin{bmatrix}
 A & B
\\
B & A
\end{bmatrix}\det D.
$$

Notably, we have
$$
\det\pmatrix{A & B\B & A} = \det(A - B) \det(A + B)
$$

Let me note a slight mistake on $P$ as the identity for $D$ is not necessarily the same for $A$. In such case, the identities used to define $P$ should be different. Namely, we need
\begin{equation}
P = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{Id}{\dim A} & 0 & 0 \ 0 & 0 & \mathrm{Id}{\dim A} \ 0 & \mathrm{Id}_{\dim D} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and $P^\top$ is the inverse.
